# Magento: How can i redirect category to another url

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How can i redirect specific category in menu to link in another website?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via .htaccess of your website.

`Redirect 301 /your_category_url_key.html http://www.yournewsite.com`

I hope this helps.